# Gnome Shell “Files & Folders” lens only finds files and folders in my home directory

Tags: files, 17.10, lenses, gnome-shell

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome Shell some days ago.

My dash finds all my applications (so it works just fine), but it only finds files and folders located directly in my home folder. It doesn't find files/folders located in subfolders of the home directory or recent files.

For example, imagine that in my home directory I have folders

- *foo1*
- *foo2*

and files

- *bar1.odt*
- *bar2.odt*

and that folder *foo1* includes file *bar3.odt*.

Also imagine that I just opened (through Nautilus and then OpenOffice) a file *bar4.odt* located in folder *foo2*.

If I type *bar3* (file in a subfolder) or *bar4* (recent file), the dash returns "No result" (I'm translating from Italian "Nessun risultato").

If I type *foo1* or *bar1*, it returns the correct results because they are directly located in my home folder.

I reinstalled `install unity-lens-files` and tried the solution by jnv (#10) in [Unity "Files & Folders" lens can't find anything](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48994/unity-files-folders-lens-cant-find-anything/49046#49046):

```
zeitgeist-daemon --quit
rm -rvf ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/fts.index/
zeitgeist-daemon --replace
```

...to no avail.

When I do `zeitgeist-daemon --replace`, I receive this warning message:

```
$ zeitgeist-daemon --replace
[16:48:00.914102 WARNING] zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
[16:48:01.355342 WARNING] zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!

** (zeitgeist-datahub:3580): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
```

In `/usr/share/unity/client-scopes.json` the line about the `unity-lens-files` reads as follows:

```
"unity-lens-files": ["files-local.scope"],
```

In dconf / desktop / unity / lenses / files, the `use-locate` option is set to `ON`.

In settings / search, the `File` option is `ON`.

Comment: I edited my own question as I found out that my Gnome Shell comes with Gnome Shell, not Unity. So my question stays the same, but it regards Gnome Shell.

Comment: For what it's worth, Zeitgeist emits the same error messages on my computer, but they seem not to be critical because it's still working. As mentioned in the answers, Gnome Shell is using Tracker rather than Zeitgeist for file search.

Comment: A quick way to ensure that Zeitgeist is working is this command `sqlite3 ~/.local/share/zeitgeist/activity.sqlite 'select timestamp from event order by timestamp desc limit 1'`. The value should increase every time you open or close a file.

Comment: I think [zeitgeist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeitgeist_(free_software)) is the wrong tool, since it doesn't index but journals activity. You need an indexer, see answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNOME shell only indexes some files in your home directory or in the "default" folders.

However, for 17.10, a decision was made **not** to automatically install the necessary tools to modify the index, namely `tracker`. This is due some [concerns](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1666676) that it might be too invasive and/or too taxing to CPU and io.(*)

```
sudo apt-get install tracker
```

If you have installed `tracker`you can edit the search via the **Settings** menu:

1. Go to *Settings*
2. Navigate to *Search*
3. Make sure you have *Files* turned on and maybe disable the other searches  you don't like (i.e. *Software Center*, *Calendar*, etc)
4. Click the little gear (⚙️) button at the bottom to open the menu
   [image: Search options menu with tracker]
5. Then navigate to *Other* and click the plus (**+**) symbol to add other search-paths
   [image: add custom search path with plus]
6. After you have closed the *Settings* panels, you can either log-out and back in or start the index manually with

`tracker daemon -s`

You can then check its progress with

```
tracker status
```

and get an output similar to this:

```
Currently indexed: 3556 files, 174 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 170.5 GB (69.29%)
All data miners are idle, indexing complete
```

---

(*) *Personally, I've not seen any negativ side effects. In fact, on my modern SSD the index process is finished in seconds for ~3500 files with 54GB in total.*

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the issue for me. I'd also like to thank Ian MacKinnon for the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

GNOME shell by default indexes files which are in your home directory or in the "default" folders (Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures and Videos).

But you can manually add a folder to be included for searching. To do that follow the steps below.

1. Open *Settings*.
2. Navigate to *Search* option. Make sure "*Files*" is turned on
   [image]
3. Click on the cogwheel (⚙️) at the bottom. A window should pop up.
4. Go to the "*Other*" tab.
5. Click on the **+** icon and add the folder you want to be included for searching.
   [image]
6. Reboot.

---

It seems `tracker` is no longer installed by default in Ubuntu 17.10 (see [Robert Riedl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1001846/480481)), you'll have to install `tracker` manually first.

Comment: This was also useful: you can customize the indexed folders. Thank you.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.10, you cannot anymore access settings to change the scope